# I'd like to build a Skype extension and have no idea how

Tags: skype

We use skype at work for almost all of our communication. Most of us are on Macs. I'd like to build an extension that checks text for a certain pattern, and links that pattern to a certain URL. We use Jira for ticketing, and it would be great if someone typed `ABC-123` if that would automatically link to the jira ticket.

I'm a web developer, mainly front end, and have no clue where to even begin writing something for the mac skype client (currently on 5.1).

I'd love the following to happen:

- Someone types [A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{1,6}.
- The extension replaces that with `<a href="http://ourjiraurl.com/$1">$1</a>`
- ...
- profit.

Thanks for any and all guidance.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take a look at the [Skype developer site](https://developer.skype.com/), and then ask here when you have a specific question.

Comment: https://extras.skype.com/ is also a god place to start - you can look at existing projects, I'm sure some of them are open-source and you could hit the ground running.

Comment: @Oli Welp, I guess "can you push C++ knowledge into my brain". :) Thanks for the link.

Comment: @asafallows thanks. Checking them out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to know C# or C++ here is a link to a how-to for C++

http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/blog/writing-a-skype-plugin-in-c

Comment: I think I'll be asking someone for help on this one.. ha. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome I would help more but I know no C# and I don't know that much C++